# \usetikzlibrary in Plain TeX gives a command not found error

Tags: tikz-pgf, plain-tex

Here is my Plain TeX file:

```
\input miniltx%
\input graphicx.sty%
\input tikz.tex%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\nopagenumbers%
\pdfpagewidth 8.5truein
\pdfpageheight 11truein
\baselineskip=12pt
\hsize=6.3truein
\vsize=8.7truein
\tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (current page.west) -- (current page.east);
\draw (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\node[draw,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at ($(current page.north west)+(0.5,0.5)$);
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

This results in the following compilation error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.23 \usetikzlibrary
                    {calc}%
?
```

I'm running on a recently install TeX Live.

Comment: Don't use redundant percent characters at end lines. Your first percent causes: the `\input graphicx.sty` is processed before the name `miniltx` is scanned. Your second percent causes: the `\input tikz.tex` is processed before `miniltx` and `graphicx.sty` are scanned. Your third percent causes: the `\usetikzlibrary` is processed before `miniltx`, `graphicx.sty` and `tikz` are scanned (but it is undefined in this time). Your fourth percent is reundant: we are in vertical mode. Your fifth percent is redundant: token processor finalizes a control sequence here without producing space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should not end the `\input` line with the %:  TeX does not have a chance to parse file name. The log shows that `tikz.tex` is never read in. Space or new line is needed here.
2. You need a (possibly empty) node text.

This works:

```
\input miniltx
\input graphicx.sty
\input tikz.tex
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%
\nopagenumbers%
\pdfpagewidth 8.5truein
\pdfpageheight 11truein
\baselineskip=12pt
\hsize=6.3truein
\vsize=8.7truein
\tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (current page.west) -- (current page.east);
\draw (current page.north) -- (current page.south);
\node[draw,inner sep=0pt,anchor=north west] at ($(current page.north
west)+(0.5,0.5)$) {};
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```