# Drawing Tikz function domain/codomain on selected set of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, block, domain

I am trying to draw a flow-chart like diagram to conceptualize a decision process by which 1) an initiator first chooses whom to team up with and 2) what task(s) to do with this or that person.

I found this previous [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72719/how-to-draw-function-domain-co-domain-range-diagram) that addresses what I am up to but its `\.fit` function applies to all three sets of nodes, while I only intend to define block environments on set B and C (since my set A contains only one node). Also, I have rather long names/texts for some of the tasks listed in set C, the block environment created by `\.fit` will not grow to the length of those long texts. The end result being that the block cut through those long texts.

To get the sense of the idea, here's an example `Tex` code I modified from that earlier topic:

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc}
        \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
        \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={on grid},
        setA/.style={fill=black, circle, inner sep=1.2pt},
        setC/.style={fill=red, rectangle,inner sep=2pt},
        every fit/.style={draw, fill=white,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt, text width=80pt},>=latex]

         % set A
        \node [setA, label=left:a] (a) {};
        \node[above=of a,anchor=south] {};

        % set B
        \node[inner sep=0pt,right=5cm of a] (x) {Person x};
        \node[below = of x] (y) {Person y};
        \node[inner sep=0pt,below = of y] (z) {Person z};
        \node[above=of x,anchor=south] {$B$};

        % set C
        \node[setC,label=right:$m$,right = 6cm of x] (m) {Task a: xxxxxx};
        \node[setC,label=right:$n$,below = of m] (n) {Task b: yyyyy};
        \node[setC,label=right:$p$,below = of n] (p) {Task c: zzzzz};
        \node[above=of m,anchor=south] {$C$};

       % the arrows
       \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (a) -- node[label=above:$f$] {} (x);
       \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (b) -- node[label=above:$f$] {} (x);
       \draw[->] (c) -- node[label=above:$g$] {} (y);
       \draw[->,shorten <= 3pt] (x) -- node[label=above:$h$] {} (m);
       \draw[->] (n) -- node[label=above:$u$] {} (y);

       % the boxes around the sets
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \node[fit= (a)  (c) ] {};
      \node[fit= (x) (z) ] {};
      \node[fit= (m) (p)] {};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}
```

which produced the following

[image]

While my desired output should look something like this

[image]

But the difficulty is that I do not know how to turn off the block environment on set A and expand the width of the block on set C to accommodate the extra length of the texts. (# remove `draw` on `every fit\.style` will turn off block environment on all sets, is there any way to only include set B and C in the block environment?)

I have referenced this other [post](http://%5Cnode%20[setA,%20below%20=%20of%20a,label=left:USA]%20(USA)%20%7B%7D;%20%20%5Cnode[above=of%20USA,anchor=south]%20%7B$A$%7D;) on `overleaf` but the complexity of his code is beyond me.

Would anyone care to take a look at and enlighten me on how to work on my existing code to produce the desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code contains self-contradicting lines like ` \node [setA, below = of a,label=left:Initiator] (a) {};`. How can `a` be below itself? Further, the fits do fit the node texts, but not the labels. What are the labels good for? Can't you just append the labels to the node texts?

Comment: I will edit that part. `label` is the text that will appear on the node.

Comment: You may also want to add a screen shot of the output of the code after you repaired it and indicate what you want to have changed.

Comment: Please check if [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59014/121799) helps you. BTW, your code still does not compile.

Comment: The essences of these two posts are different. I read that post before but it did not address what I intend to do.

Comment: So far you have posted a code that does not compile, even after I told you twice that it does not, you did not fix it. And if one ignores the errors, the most striking flaw of the output is the one addressed in [How to use "fit" to frame the nodes and labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59012/how-to-use-fit-to-frame-the-nodes-and-labels). And if you do not want to box `a` just drop `\node[fit= (a)  (c) ] {};`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code, which replicate your second image, can be as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 24mm,
  start chain = going below,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, node contents={}},
  setC/.style = {rectangle, inner sep=2pt, text depth=1ex,
                 anchor=west, on chain},
   FIT/.style = {rectangle, draw, %rounded corners=5pt,
                 inner xsep=8pt, inner ysep=4pt, font=\sffamily,
                 fit=#1},
   Arr/.style = {-Triangle, shorten >=3pt},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, sloped, pos=0.6}
                        ]
% from right to left
% set C
\node[setC] (m) {Task a: xxxxxx};
\node[setC] (n) {Task b: yyyyy};
\node[setC] (p) {Task c: zzzzz};
\node[FIT=(m) (p), label=$C$]   {};
% set B
\node[setC, left=of m]  (x) {Person x};
\node[setC]             (y) {Person y};
\node[setC]             (z) {Person z};
\node[FIT=(x) (z), label=$B$]   {};
% set A
\node [setC,left=of y]  (a) {Initiator};
% the arrows
\draw[Arr]   (a.east) edge["$f$"] (x.west)
             (a.east) edge["$g$"] (y.west)
             (x.east) edge["$h$"] (p.west)
             (n.west)  to ["$u$"] (y.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

this image differ from what you generate with your code (in case that it would work).

since from your question is not clear (to me), what you like to have, my main effort was to make your code simpler, more consistent and shorter. for this i use `tikz` libraries `chains` and `quotes`.

in case, that you like to have nodes in "C" with red fill and labels, this is simple to add. for node "a" in your code, i prepare style `dot` but not use it.

Comment: I was unable to replicate your answer. What I got was a one line of code `, fit = 1CBfghu` There are `undefined control sequence` all over the place.

Comment: do you test (by compiling with pdflatex) my mwe as it is? in my code doesn't exist `, fit = 1CBfghu` .  showed image is obtain with code in answer.

Comment: Strangely, I could not get your code to run on my Winedt nor on sharelatex. I did reference [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360439/usetikzlibrary-in-plain-tex-gives-a-command-not-found-error), but their recommended solution didn't work.

Comment: I also tried loading `tikz` using `usepackage{tikz}` and after `documentclass{article}` command, but it didn't work. What `Tex` editor are you using?

Comment: @user37891, ups, when i copied code, i accidentally miss the first code line, now corrected. i use `winedt 10.2` as editor and `64-bit miktex` for `latex`, recent version.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks so much for helping on this. I am also working on the code provided by @marmot.

Comment: @user37891,  you can do this, but i don't see any benefits doing this. it might happen, that with this nodes will overlap. if you like to make image wider, than change `node distance`. it is defined as `node distance = <vertical distance between nodes> and <horizontal distance between nodes>`.  if vertical distances are ok, than try for example `node distance = 4mm and 32mm`. for more spaces between nodes and FIT node you can increase `inner sep`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is an answer, but it is at least a code that compiles without errors and looks a bit more than the desired output.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes,fit,calc}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={on grid},
    setA/.style={fill=black, circle, inner sep=1.2pt},
    setC/.style={fill=red, rectangle,inner sep=2pt},
    every fit/.style={draw, fill=white,rectangle,rounded corners=5pt, text width=80pt},>=latex]

     % set A
    \node [setA, label=left:a] (a) {};
    \node[above=of a,anchor=south] {};

    % set B
    \node[inner sep=0pt,right=5cm of a] (y) {Person y};
    \node[above = of y] (x) {Person x};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,below = of y] (z) {Person z};
    \node[above=of x,anchor=south] {$B$};

    % set C
    \node[setC,label={[name=ml] right:$m$},right = 6cm of x] (m) {Task a: xxxxxx};
    \node[setC,label={[name=nl] right:$n$},below = of m] (n) {Task b: yyyyy};
    \node[setC,label={[name=pl] right:$p$},below = of n] (p) {Task c: zzzzz};
    \node[above=of m,anchor=south] {$C$};

   % the arrows
   \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (a) -- node[label=above:$f$] {} (x);
   \draw[->,shorten >= 3pt] (a) -- node[label=below:$f$] {} (y);
```

%       \draw[->] (c) -- node[label=above:$g$] {} (y);
       \draw[->,shorten <= 3pt] (x) -- node[label=above:$h$] {} (m);
       \draw[->] (n) -- node[label=above:$u$] {} (y);

```
   % the boxes around the sets
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
```

%      \node[fit= (a)  (c) ] {};
      \node[fit= (x) (z) ] {};
      \node[fit= (m) (ml) (p)] {};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{document}

[image]

Comment: I am also experimenting with your code and see if I can modify it to fit my purpose.